# execute command on GCP GKE node

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to execute command on GCP GKE node but I need to do it without manually sshing to the machine.

What I need:

1. adding ntp.keys
2. configuring ntp.conf
3. restart ntp daemon (here I encountered a problem)

Point 1 and 2 can be easly achived with DaemonSet. I mounted /etc/ntp/ directory to init container and created right files. Unofrtunately point 3 seems to be impossible. Is there any way I can run "systemctl restart ntp" on each node of the cluster?

My problem is mainly due to GCP API does not provide nodes endpoint so I can't get IPs of nodes and then run ansible to perform NTP configuration.
The goal is to **automatically **

1. provision cluster (with terraform)
2. configure NTP client on each node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right path, If you don't want to SSH into the node and manual job, what you can do is like create one **Daemonset** and automate **SSH** process.

**Daemonset** runs on all available **nodes** in **Cluster**. You can mount your **shell** **script** to **Node** path and **execute** it by doing **SSH** from **Image**.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: daemonset-access
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cron-namespace-admin-rbac
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: daemonset-access
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: umalog
  labels:
    k8s-app: umalog
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: umalog
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: umalog
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: daemonset-access
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
      - command:
        - bash
        - -c        
        - |
          mkdir -p /work-dir/filter_config
          while true;
          do
            echo "inside while";
            /root/reload-uma.sh;
            sleep 1800;
          done        
        image: oraclelinux:8
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: daemon-ssh
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /root/reload-uma.sh
          name: uma-agent-reload
          subPath: reload-uma.sh
        - mountPath: /work-dir-ssh
          name: do-node-ssh
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 511
          name: uma-agent-reload
        name: uma-agent-reload
      - hostPath:
          path: /home/opc/.ssh
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
        name: do-node-ssh
```

**Configmap**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: uma-agent-reload
data:
  reload-uma.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash -x
    cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /work-dir-ssh/authorized_keys
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <User-name-ssh>@`kubectl -n default get pod $HOSTNAME -o yaml | grep hostIP | awk -d: {'print $2'} | tail -1` 
    sudo systemctl reload <your-service-agent>.service
```

Comment: I'm currently testing your solution. I can already say that getting IP with kubectl is not possible since kubectl is not installed on container. I used status.hostIP insted. Second thing is that we need to generate ssh keys before redirecting it to authorized_keys. Right now I'm struggeling with sshing from container to host machine. Despite of having correct public id_rsa in autohorized_keys on host machine I'm constantly getting Permission Denied.

Comment: you are right we need to have the kubectl in image, or else nodes need to have proper SSH keys we can also do without keys however i am not sure you are on which cloud. are you adding proper private and public key coz as you notice `/home/opc/.ssh` is the Oracle user path did you update that ? with proper it should have worked we been using it for a year with Oracle cloud.

Comment: do you mean something like this error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75784916/ssh-to-gke-node-from-pod i am trying to SSH without Keys to nodes using ServiceAccount from GKE POD. also for IP you can use the downward API of k8s and get the Node IP as Env var and use it directly.

Comment: I was trying ssh with root:<ip>. Now I change root to my user and it works fine. Seems that only last problem left which is:
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
This error occure when command systemctl restart chronyd is executed

Comment: try with service instead with systemctl command once

Comment: I was able to restart it with command:
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <user>@<ip_adress> 'sudo systemctl restart chronyd'
so comand had to be parsed as parameter to ssh otherwise I was getting error like in message above. Thank you for your help! I realy appreciate it.